# CSS colgroup and td borders conflict

Tags: css

when you have a border on a colgroup or col in css, it doesn't seem to matter what you do it will be overridden by td borders. How can you prevent this from happening?

see http://jsbin.com/suteralaru/2/edit

Comment: what do you do with the colgroup there? it's not html valid.

Comment: Deprecated != invalid

Comment: @sdcr MDN says `colgroup` was deprecated in HTML4.01 and is obsolete in HTML5. However, the [HTML4.01 list of elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/elements.html) doesn't list it as deprecated, and it isn't in the [HTML5 list of obsolete elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features). However, the markup is invalid: there is only one `col` element, which has `span="2"`, but the rows are 3 column wide.

Comment: thanks for the correction. @user3455992 why do you need colgroup there? you can apply to the <th> tags if you need different styles.

Comment: this is a dumbed down version of my real table with 11 rows that all have headers and then are grouped into 4 columns with 2,3,3,3 rows respectively.The cells each need borders and the columns need clear defining borders as well.

Comment: if it's not valid anymore then what takes it's place? column-count and column-gap are not production ready

Comment: just to be clear, I want the border for the colgroup to go all the way down the table, not just on the TH. That's the goal

Comment: I still don't understand it, but will this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006089/setting-rowspan-on-colgroup and this http://css-tricks.com/row-and-column-highlighting/